# C++ implement generic class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a generic class in C++ but I am getting the error "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token " on lines 6, 16, 19...

I am just creating a simple class and pretty sure I can go on from there. Here is the sample code I am dealing with:

```
using namespace std;

//line 6  
generic < class T>  
class Table  
{  
 friend class Table;  
        Table< T> *LT;  
        LT_Node* cursor;  

 public:  
        Table();    
        ~Table();  
        Table(const Table  & source);  
        Table& operator =(const Table& rhs);  
};

//line 16  
generic < class T>  
Table< T>::Table(){}

//line 19  
generic < class T>  
Table< T>::~Table(){}

generic < class T>  
Table< T>::Table(const Table  & source){}

generic < class T>  
Table::Table& operator =(const Table& rhs){}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using this `generic` word?  What makes you think that this would work?

Comment: Thinking of C++ templates as 'generic classes' is ignoring a huge facet of the power they have. Of course, with that power comes complexity, so you might want to ignore it. :-) And, like @James McNellis, I'm also really curious as to why you thought you should be using the word 'generic' instead of 'template'? Did you see it in an example somewhere or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is ordinary C++ the keyword isn't `generic` but `template`. You are defining a template for a class or function, that is later instantiated when used.

Comment: I see. I thought there may be a generic keyword since I am doing a school lab on implementing generics so I would like to use that if there is. If not, template seems to be working but getting another error here:  Table<T>::Table& operator =(const Table<T>& rhs){}

Comment: Here you write Table<T>::Table&, which is correct, but that is not exactly what you have in your code.

Comment: Well, above it I wrote **Table<T>::Table(const Table<T>& source){}** and seems to work but I get an error with the line **Table<T>::Table& operator =(const Table<T>& rhs){}** with the same error as before.

Comment: Nevermind, just silly syntax error. Thx for the help, it seems to be working now :))